# How to remove 25% of number value of span using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I want to remove `25%` from a price and then show the sum in a new span. Something like this:

```
price * 0.8 = newPrice //edited
```

This is my span:

```
<span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">21.188</span>
```

Here is what I've come up with so far...

```
$(".purchase-block-price" ).each(function() {

    // Show price ex vat
    var price = parseInt($(".price").text().trim().replace(".",""));
    var newprice = price * 0.8;

    $(newprice).appendTo(".purchase-block-price");
});
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: It is definitely possible. As SO is for educating, not spoon feeding answers, please show the code that you tried which you're having an issue with.

Comment: see i update my answer now

Comment: I'm sorry about that @RoryMcCrossan but this is my first post. I'll see if I can add my crappy code

Comment: @mellaker don't worry about your code quality - that's why we're all here to help. Thanks for updating the question. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop over the `.price` elements, take the `text()` value from them and convert it to a floating point number using `parseFloat()`. From there you can calculate the value, minus 20% and insert a new `span` containing the value. Try this:

```js
$(".purchase-block-price .price").each(function() {
  var price = parseFloat($(this).text().trim());
  var newprice = price * 0.75;
  $('<span class="newprice">' + newprice + '</span>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

```css
.price {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.newprice {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purchase-block-price">
  <span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">21.188</span>
</div>
<div class="purchase-block-price">
  <span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">132.299</span>
</div>
```

Note that you can use the `.toFixed(2)` method to round the calculated price values if required.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, sort of. I need to get rid of the dot before the calculation since it marks thousends in Sweden. I tried .replace(".","") but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually it did work with replace(). Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, get the value (in this case with `text()`) and multiply by 0.75.

```js
var value = parseFloat( $("#ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice").text() );
var newValue = value * 0.75;
console.log( newValue );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">21.188</span>
```

Comment: @YaseenAhmed... please explain... 21.188 - 25% = 15.891... 21.188 * 0.75 = 15.891 ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```js
var oldprice = $('#ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice').text();
var newprice = oldprice - (oldprice * 0.20);
console.log(newprice); /* Do whatever you want with your new price*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">21.188</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.text( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) to replacing current value of span with new value.

```
$("#ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice").text(function(i, text){
  return text - (text * 0.25); // or text * 0.75
});
```

```js
$("#ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice").text(function(i, text){
  return text * 0.75;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ctl00_main_ctl00_ctl00_labPrice" class="price" itemprop="price">21.188</span>
```